# Grid view row is altered when alert messaged is displayed

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, .net

I am facing some issues in an ASP.NET Web forms application ( .NET framework 2.0) .In my Grid View Row Data bound event , I am assigning a css class to a row  that is dynamically added in this method for a given condition as shown below

```
if (some condition)
{
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex + 1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
    row.CssClass = "StdGridHeader";
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.Text = "SOME TEXT";
    cell1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
    cell1.ColumnSpan = 4;
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    ((GridView)sender).Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(joernsAccCount + 1, row);
}
```

The CSS is applied when the page is rendered as required.On the click of the continue button on the same page, an alert message is displayed. The code for displaying the alert message is as shown below

```
string strJavascript = "alert('some text'); window.location='" +
"../sample.aspx';";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Message", strJavascript, true);
```

Here's where something unexpected happens.
When the alert message is displayed, the CSS applied to the specific row in the grid vanishes and it visually appears similar to the other rows in the grid.

I can't seem to understand why this is happening.

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: The alert is generated by a postback. You need to re-add the rows in the postback (the client is getting a new page, it only contains what is generated on the server).